# Moving combo box up dynamically when changing combo box?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I'm using Flex builder 4.5. I'm having five combos in my web application. 
Combo 1 loads as staff and student.
Combo 2 loads department, 
Combo 3 loads staff names, 
Combo 4 loads student batch and 
Combo 5 loads student names respectively.

When i'm selecting student in 1st combo, combo 4 and combo 5 should move up dynamically. Kindly advise on this...

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to manipulate the coordinates of controls. Instead of it I would use a ViewStack control and change the selected index according to the item of the first combo.

So you have more control over your view representation and less problem with future changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">
    <s:ComboBox id="cbMain" selectedIndex="0">
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:Object label="Staff"/>
            <fx:Object label="Student"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:ComboBox>

    <mx:ViewStack id="vsMain" width="200" height="200" selectedIndex="{cbMain.selectedIndex}">
        <s:NavigatorContent id="ncStaff" width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:VGroup>
                <s:ComboBox id="cbStaffDep" selectedIndex="0">
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:Object label="Department01"/>
                        <fx:Object label="Department02"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:ComboBox>

                <s:ComboBox id="cbStaffName" selectedIndex="0">
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:Object label="StaffName01"/>
                        <fx:Object label="StaffName02"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:ComboBox>
            </s:VGroup>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent id="ncStudent" width="100%" height="100%">

            <s:VGroup>
                <s:ComboBox id="cbStudentBatch" selectedIndex="0">
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:Object label="Batch01"/>
                        <fx:Object label="Batch02"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:ComboBox>

                <s:ComboBox id="cbStudentName" selectedIndex="0">
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <fx:Object label="StudentName01"/>
                        <fx:Object label="StudentName02"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:ComboBox>
            </s:VGroup>

        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:ViewStack>

</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```